# Putting actions to externally loaded swf file

Tags: flash, action, external

I have a problem regarding putting interactivity to exernally loaded swf files. I have no problem loading the swf files but when it comes to putting actions on it (mouse click)my swf file doesn't seem to work. In the other hand, when i remove the "SWF_object.addEventListener(MouseEvent.Click,moveSwf);" the swf file displays properly.

```
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.display.Loader;

SWF_object.addEventListener(MouseEvent.Click,moveSwf);
var SWF_object : Loader = new Loader();
var SWF_object2 : Loader = new Loader();
var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest("sample.swf");
//SWFobject.loadMovie("sample.swf");
SWF_object.load(url);
SWF_object2.load(url);
addChild(SWF_object);
addChild(SWF_object2);

SWF_object2.x=300;
SWF_object.x=-100;
SWF_object.y=0;
```

//////////////////////

```
function moveSwf(event:MouseEvent){

SWF_object.x=1000;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that I notice is that you are adding a listener to an object that has not yet been instantiated.

Your code should look more like this:

```
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.display.Loader;

var SWF_object : Loader = new Loader();
var SWF_object2 : Loader = new Loader();
var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest("sample.swf");
//SWFobject.loadMovie("sample.swf");
SWF_object.load(url);
SWF_object2.load(url);
addChild(SWF_object);
addChild(SWF_object2);
SWF_object.addEventListener(MouseEvent.Click,moveSwf);

SWF_object2.x=300;
SWF_object.x=-100;
SWF_object.y=0;
```

As you can see, you would add the listener after you have instantiated that object, and in this case, after you have added that object to the display list.

Comment: It would be great if you could accept an answer if it helped you, or at least mention that the answer i provided didn't work for you and why...